# ASP.net/VB.net Generating a data bound form at runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, sqldatasource

I'm currently trying to put together code that will dynamically generate a set of HTML form controls at runtime, and then databind those controls. From what I've read, you can't databind form controls like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc, however all of the information I can find on this was from a few years ago. Not sure if it's possible to do this with .net 4.5 now or not.

In any case, what I'm asking is what the best way is to accomplish what I'm trying to do, whether it's utilizing what I already have, or going at it from a completely different direction.

The goal of this dynamically generated form is two-fold:

1. The ability to create/modify/delete news posts on an existing website
2. The ability to reuse this code with as little code change as possible

Here is my current code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %> 
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)    
    Dim dataSourceInfo As New DataSourceInfo
    dataSourceInfo.TableName = "Post_Table"
    dataSourceInfo.DataColumns = {"PostTitle", "PostContent", "PostURL", "PublishDate", "ExpirationDate", "Active"}
    dataSourceInfo.KeyColumn = "ID"

    BuildCMSForm(dataSourceInfo)
    BindCMSForm(dataSourceInfo)
    End Sub

    Public Structure DataSourceInfo
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim DataColumns() As String
    Dim KeyColumn As String
    End Structure

    Public Sub BuildCMSForm(ByVal dataSourceInfo As DataSourceInfo)
    Dim dataSource As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
    Dim strSelectCommand As String
    dataSource.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
    dataSource.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test_Web;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    strSelectCommand = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE " & _
        "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " & _
        "WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" & dataSourceInfo.TableName & "' " & _
        "AND COLUMN_NAME IN ("

    For Each col As String In dataSourceInfo.DataColumns
        strSelectCommand = strSelectCommand & "'" & col.ToString & "', "
    Next

    strSelectCommand = strSelectCommand.Substring(0, strSelectCommand.Length - 2) & ")"
    dataSource.SelectCommand = strSelectCommand

    Dim dv As DataView
    dv = CType(dataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)

    For Each row As DataRow In dv.Table.Rows()
        Dim newControlDiv As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
        newControlDiv.Attributes.Add("id", "CMSControlDiv" & row.Item(0).ToString)
        newControlDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "CMSControlDiv")
        newControlDiv.InnerHtml = row.Item(0).ToString & ":<br />"

        Select Case row.Item(1).ToString
        Case "text"
            Dim newControl As TextBox = New TextBox
            newControl.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine
            newControl.ID = row.Item(0).ToString
            newControl.Attributes.Add("class", "CMSControl")

            newControlDiv.Controls.Add(newControl)
        Case "varchar"
            Dim newControl As TextBox = New TextBox
            newControl.ID = row.Item(0).ToString
            newControl.Attributes.Add("class", "CMSControl")

            newControlDiv.Controls.Add(newControl)
        Case "datetime"
            Dim newControl As TextBox = New TextBox
            newControl.ID = row.Item(0).ToString
            newControl.Attributes.Add("class", "CMSControl")

            newControlDiv.Controls.Add(newControl)
        Case "bit"
            Dim newControl As CheckBox = New CheckBox
            newControl.ID = row.Item(0).ToString
            newControl.Attributes.Add("class", "CMSControl")

            newControlDiv.Controls.Add(newControl)
        End Select

        AdminForm.Controls.Add(newControlDiv)
    Next

    Dim newSubmit As HtmlInputSubmit = New HtmlInputSubmit
    newSubmit.Attributes.Add("id", "CMSSubmit")
    newSubmit.Value = "Submit"

    AdminForm.Controls.Add(newSubmit)
    End Sub

    Public Sub BindCMSForm(ByVal dataSourceInfo As DataSourceInfo)
    Dim dataSource As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
    Dim strSelectCommand As String
    Dim strColumns As String = ""
    dataSource.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
    dataSource.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test_Web;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    strSelectCommand = "SELECT TOP 1 {0} FROM {1} WHERE [PostType] = 'Event'"

    For Each col As String In dataSourceInfo.DataColumns
        strColumns = strColumns & "[" & col.ToString & "], "
    Next

    strColumns = strColumns.Substring(0, strColumns.Length - 2)
    dataSource.SelectCommand = String.Format(strSelectCommand, strColumns, dataSourceInfo.TableName)

    Dim dv As DataView
    dv = CType(dataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)

    For Each col As DataColumn In dv.Table.Columns()

    Next
    End Sub
</script>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper" runat="server">
        <div id="Content" class="Content" runat="server">
        <form id="AdminForm" runat="server">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a LOT of work.  In order to capture changes made by users, you're going to have to reconstruct your control set on every postback, and keep a lot of metadata in view state or session so you know what control belongs to what database field when you need to update.

I would suggest looking harder at some of the built in controls, such as the `FormView` and `DetailsView`.  If memory serves, they can auto-generate input controls for the columns in a result set.  If you need to fine-tune how they do it (say, by excluding the primary key fields) you can subclass the control and alter its selection of columns to render.

While it is true that they probably won't be exactly suited to your purpose, "settling for 90% of perfection saves 50% of effort".  And they represent a lot of functionality that you won't have to write, test, or support.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Ann! Now that I know what kind of work I was trying to get myself into, I'll probably come at this using FormView. Also, I really like that quote... "settling for 90% of perfection saves 50% of effort." I'll remember that one.